# Error white waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: android-studio, gradle

There's a red line in the "app" part of my Android Studio project. I don't know what's going on and where I was wrong:

[image]

I have tried Invalidate Cache, I have tried checking the Gradle scripts, and yet everything looks correct.

Here is the current output.

[image: Current output]

> Error white waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: try to build the project and share the build output. This way we can help you out identifying the issue

Comment: I have. It's on the edited question.

Comment: "Error white waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online." seems pretty clear English to me...?   (But why was it posted in a picture, text is so much easier to read.....)